# Can I use the term "tweets" for posts at my own site?

Tags: trademark, trade-name

Can I use the term "tweets" for posts at my own site? And if I put the word "tweet" in quotes?

Comment: Regardless of trademark, it would be poor choice because it would be confusing to your readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see on the USPTO registry, "tweet" is still not trademarked for the purposes you're talking about.

Twitter has been working to secure that trademark, but I can't find any record of them having actually secured it.

Just the same, I'd predict that using it will get you at least a cease-and-desist letter, and possibly a lawsuit. Whether you'd win that case seems to be a very open question, but that presumes you have the resources to litigate.

Comment: Is using “chirp” instead an option?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Interesting idea.